# xslt to loops repeated occurring elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have group of elements and need to isolate them into individual sets.

Input is:

```
Records

A
B
C
D
D
D
C
C
D

A
B
C
D
D
D
D

A
B
C
C
C
C
D

/Records
```

I want to divide them into parts as follows:

```
Records 

Record
A
B 
C
C 
C  
D 
D 
D 
D
/Record

Record
A
B
C
D
D
D
/Record

/Records
```

I have tried something and am able to make it to only one C and D not repeated as shown above.

Please help.

Below is my XSLT:

```
<ns1:RoutingRecords>
     <xsl:for-each select="/imp1:RoutingRecords/imp1:A">
        <xsl:variable name="level1Count" select="position()"/>
        <ns1:RoutingRecord>
           <ns1:A>
              <ns1:Item_Number>
                 <xsl:value-of select="/imp1:RoutingRecords/imp1:A[$level1Count]/imp1:C1"/>
              </ns1:Item_Number>
           </ns1:A>
           <ns1:B>
              <ns1:End_Stckrm>
                 <xsl:value-of select="/imp1:RoutingRecords/imp1:B[$level1Count]/imp1:C1"/>
              </ns1:End_Stckrm>
           </ns1:B>
           <xsl:for-each select="$level1Count+1">
              <ns1:F>
                 <ns1:Op_Sequence>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                 </ns1:Op_Sequence>
              </ns1:F>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </ns1:RoutingRecord>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </ns1:RoutingRecords>
```

apologies for not making it clear.
my input each A B C D Records have child elements

`<Records> <A><C1>NLO84B514948AJP1 0 1 STIFFENER SHEET 001 7LNEC0</C1></A>
<B><C1>7-ST 7-B77B052214052214 $</C1></B>
<C><C1>001 000100010050000</C1></C>
<D><C1>P1 LABOR IN G1</C1></D>`

Comment: Some clarification: do you know in advance that you're going to have types A, B, C, D, etc, and you're just trying to group them together, or are types A, B, C, D, etc unknown until you begin?

Comment: You should update your input/output to be XML so we can see the actual structure of what you're trying to do. Are A/B/C/D just children of Records? Also, what version of XSLT.

Comment: awesome, never expected such a fast reply. @Welbog yeah inside my Records tag will have A B C D Records multiple time and i know the element name forehand, but the issue is C and D can occur multiple times and not sure the number of occurrences.

Comment: @Daniel Haley. i can use 2.0 also if we have specific function in it. A B C D are children of Records, want to separate each set of A B C and D (C and D can occur multiple times) into group called Record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super easy with XSLT 2.0 using [`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group).

**XML Input** (Added values to elements to help show correct grouping.)

```
<Records>

    <A>
        <C1>NLO84B514948AJP1 0 1 STIFFENER SHEET 001 7LNEC0</C1>
    </A>
    <B>
        <C1>7-ST 7-B77B052214052214 $</C1>
    </B>
    <C>
        <C1>001 000100010050000</C1>
    </C>
    <D>
        <C1>P1 LABOR IN G1</C1>
    </D>

    <A>g1</A>
    <B>g1</B>
    <C>g1</C>
    <D>g1</D>
    <D>g1</D>
    <D>g1</D>
    <C>g1</C>
    <C>g1</C>
    <D>g1</D>

    <A>g2</A>
    <B>g2</B>
    <C>g2</C>
    <D>g2</D>
    <D>g2</D>
    <D>g2</D>
    <D>g2</D>

    <A>g3</A>
    <B>g3</B>
    <C>g3</C>
    <C>g3</C>
    <C>g3</C>
    <C>g3</C>
    <D>g3</D>

</Records>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="A">
                <Record>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>                    
                </Record>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Records>
   <Record>
      <A>
         <C1>NLO84B514948AJP1 0 1 STIFFENER SHEET 001 7LNEC0</C1>
      </A>
      <B>
         <C1>7-ST 7-B77B052214052214 $</C1>
      </B>
      <C>
         <C1>001 000100010050000</C1>
      </C>
      <D>
         <C1>P1 LABOR IN G1</C1>
      </D>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <A>g1</A>
      <B>g1</B>
      <C>g1</C>
      <D>g1</D>
      <D>g1</D>
      <D>g1</D>
      <C>g1</C>
      <C>g1</C>
      <D>g1</D>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <A>g2</A>
      <B>g2</B>
      <C>g2</C>
      <D>g2</D>
      <D>g2</D>
      <D>g2</D>
      <D>g2</D>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <A>g3</A>
      <B>g3</B>
      <C>g3</C>
      <C>g3</C>
      <C>g3</C>
      <C>g3</C>
      <D>g3</D>
   </Record>
</Records>
```

Here's an XSLT 1.0 version that, using the same input above, produces the same output as above.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|A"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select=".|following-sibling::*[not(self::A) and generate-id(preceding-sibling::A[1])=generate-id(current())]"/>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: seems results not pretty much expected. im seeing results in the single Record. adding the source and expeted target xmls below.

Comment: @user3803083 Edit your **question**.

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>    is this the change i need

Comment: @user3803083 I suggest you add the required output to your question too.

Comment: <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="A">
                <RoutingRecord>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </RoutingRecord>
            </xsl:for-each-group>

Comment: changes as above seems to be returning the data, i need the output as shown above as grouping, the xslt given above was working with out child elements in the xml. thanks all for the help

Comment: @user3803083 - The `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>` copies the entire element, including children. I updated my example to show children being copied.

Comment: Hey Daniel, Can we able to achieve this in XSLT 1.0, unfortunately my OSB service is not allowing me XSLT 2.0 please give your thoughts

Comment: @Sujan - I added an XSLT 1.0 option.

Comment: Awesome, you are simple awesome Daniel. Many Thanks again.